# How do determine if a site uses amazon's web services?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is there any way to tell if a website uses amazon's web services, or are all the API calls hidden after the browser renders the code?

I am trying to figure out if this website uses amazon's web services.

http://www.toms.com/

I did a search on the source in the homepage on "cloudfront" and it came up, but that was in the javascript, hehe.

I know the rest of the site is in php/mysql.  So I suspect that the API calls were done in php which causes the calls to be hidden when they're rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this their server is in Ohio (at least, their IP is)

http://whois.domaintools.com/toms.com

CloudFront has no servers in Ohio.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

Their DNS is also not resolved by Route 53 or Amazon.

Comment: Re: the deleted comment -- If they were using Amazon CloudFront, whatever edge location you connected to would still be owned by Amazon. If they were using EC2, their load balancer in front of the many servers would still be owned by Amazon. It does mean something.

Comment: lol, why do you think i deleted it, it's the impulsive writing after realizing you asked a bad question lol

Comment: Sometimes if you ping a site from the command line, you will get an amazonaws IP as a response. TYPE IN `$ ping somesite.com`
 RESPONSE: `PING ec2-54-241-6-212.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (54.241.6.212): 56 data bytes`

Answer (score 3):

Amazon has [26 different web services](http://aws.amazon.com/).

You can tell if the web server you are communicating with is hosted by Amazon EC2 by its IP address. You can't tell if there are EC2 instances behind a proxy you're talking to, though.

You can tell if the domain name is resolved by an Amazon Route 53 DNS server.

Besides that, you wouldn't really know what other services are being used unless they choose to make it obvious.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the answer.  How can I "tell"?  Can you give me a play-by-play in firebug please?

Comment: You don't see anything in Firebug. You look up the owner of the IP the domain resolves to with ARIN/RIPE. You look up the owner of the IP of the primary DNS server with ARIN/RIPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching the HTTP traffic from this website with [Fidder](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Also, CloudFront is used to distribute content quickly via a CDN. It HAS to be used with Amazon S3. So they are using S3 which technically is part of Amazon's "Web Services"